# Need help in configuring default editor in pry on windows

Tags: pry

i am facing issues in configuring default editor in pry on windows platform.
Iam able to open pry session and within a pry session able to navigate,cd into instance variables and stop the execution using binding.pry and execute the line of code using play commands.

But not able to modify the code using edit command which is giving the error like  can not find the c:\myusernameAppLocalTemppry20160210-9320-1kn8la9.rb file

i am using ruby -> 1.9.3 pry -> 0.10.3 rspec -> 2.11.0
Kindly let me know how to configure the open the editor with pry session

Thanks in Advance
Santosh Kulkarni

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, then I created ~/.pryrc and inserted following lines (I use Vi as an editor).

```
Pry.config.editor = "vi"
Pry.config.editor = proc { |file, line| "vi +#{line} #{file}" }
```